# Multiple foreach for get link and image

Tags: php

i want to get image url and link to image from two text file
with two for each

```
$files = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') ;

$files = preg_replace("/.+?(\\d+).*/", "$1", $files);

$count2 = $files;
$page2 = $count2 ;
$file2 = 'link.txt';
$per_page2 = 4;
$content2 = file_get_contents($file2);
$array2 = explode(PHP_EOL, $content2);
$start2 = --$page2 * $per_page2;
$lines2 = array_slice($array2, $start2, $per_page2);
$output2 = '';


foreach ($lines2 as $line2)
{
    $count = $files;
    $page1 = $count ;
    $file = 'linkimg.txt';
    $per_page = 4;
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
    $start = --$page1 * $per_page;
    $lines = array_slice($array, $start, $per_page);
    $output = '';

    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        echo '<div class="li4">';

        echo '<a href="' .$line2 .'">'  .'<img src="'   .$line .'">' .'</a>';

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

i want display image with link to other link, but not work
can help me.

Comment: What are you meaning to achieve here `files = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') ;

$files = preg_replace("/.+?(\\d+).*/", "$1", $files);` ? Are you passing arguments to your script? I'm asking this because the value of `$files` is passed around then treated as an integer. If you're using the script name to pass a value, that isn't right. Run your script with arguments instead.;

Comment: $files output is pages number,, example : if page load = 2 , script get link url line 5,6,7,8. if page load = 3 , script get line 9,10,11,12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below code.

use for loop in this scenario.

Assuming that:
1. both files have equal lines.

```
$files = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') ;

$files = preg_replace("/.+?(\\d+).*/", "$1", $files);

$count2 = $files;
$page2 = $count2 ;
$file2 = 'link.txt';
$per_page2 = 4;
$content2 = file_get_contents($file2);
$array2 = explode(PHP_EOL, $content2);
$start2 = --$page2 * $per_page2;
$lines2 = array_slice($array2, $start2, $per_page2);
$output2 = '';


 $count = $files;
    $page1 = $count ;
    $file = 'linkimg.txt';
    $per_page = 4;
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
    $start = --$page1 * $per_page;
    $lines = array_slice($array, $start, $per_page);
    $output = '';

for ($i=0;$i<count($lines2);$i++)
{
        echo '<div class="li4">';

        echo '<a href="' .$line2[$i] .'">'  .'<img src="'   .$line[$i] .'">' .'</a>';

        echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: This is effectively a code-only (low-quality) answer with syntax errors to an unclear question.  Please remove this answer.  Once the OP has posted a complete / clear / answerable question, then you may choose to undelete or post a new answer.

Comment: this work , when i change $line[i], $line2[i]  to $lines[$i], $lines2[$i] .. thanks